# Render iframe on MDI window in a flex application

Tags: apache-flex, iframe, mdi

I am working on a flex application which has MDI window structure.I have to render an iframe on one of the MDI windows.I am using the ExternalInterface class for rendering the iframe,but 
I see that iframe is rendered below the MDI window , not exactly on the MDI window.Any help on this would be great .

Answer (score 1):

If "below" means on the Y axis (not Z axis - under flash) than check the browser zoom if it is set to 100% (ctrl + scroll wheel up/down). I was wondering why my iframe was rendered out of the position and this was the cause.

Comment: true that, annoying isn't it